# I want to delete the files once the user left the conversation in the bot framework (.netcore)

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, bots, chatbot

Actually, I want to delete all the files for that particular user which logged in to my BOT and once the user left the conversation. I want them all to delete as I am storing them in my wwwroot and I don't want it to store and keep it there.
Any suggestions will be helpful. how I will be able to achieve this. I am new to this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use the ActivityHandler's OnMembersRemovedAsync method. This method provide logic for when members other than the bot leave the conversation, such as your bot's good-bye logic.

I think you could add some logic to to get the user id and delete the user according to this user ID.

More details ,you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/activityhandler?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#onMembersRemoved_BotHandler_). About how to use this activity handler, you could refer to this welcome bot [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/03.welcome-user).